# Unable to use gist in medium

Tags: gist, medium.com-publishing-api, medium-editor

I have searched a lot and tried several approaches. I believe I am doing something wrong as I am unable to have code from gist in the medium plataform bloggers.

I have only get the links on there but the code does not show or is not integrate. I have tried all the modalities of gist share code possible and paste using the embedded option in medium.

For example,

https://gist.github.com/GMoneyAccount/84fb1a9836aa91054e1714ac9d176630

https://gist.github.com/GMoneyAccount/84fb1a9836aa91054e1714ac9d176630.js">

https://gist.github.com/84fb1a9836aa91054e1714ac9d176630.git

https://gist.github.com/84fb1a9836aa91054e1714ac9d176630

https://gist.github.com/SumeraMartin/6369e704caffa8bacdaa859a1bec8b7d

https://gist.github.com/SumeraMartin/6369e704caffa8bacdaa859a1bec8b7d

This code does not show in the medium.

What I am missing? I have looked how people do but does not work for me for some reason and also I have changed from google to firefox and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

The vendor that they use for processing embeds is currently down. You can watch the status of the incident here: http://status.embed.ly/

So, basically, the way you are doing it isn't a problem. You'll just have to wait until the incident resolves.

Cheers.